# Django formset shows up in 1 app but not in the other

Tags: django, django-forms, formset

So I have this Django app `relate`. I want to use formset to display as many `Topics` I can. My problem is when I render the template nothing shows up. However, when I moved the relevant lines of code to another Django app which also uses formset, the formset works perfectly well. As much as I would want to move to the other app I wish I could try to develop from `relate`. I was thinking maybe there are implementations/imports that the other app has that allows it to implement my formset. But I examined everything and I haven't found any that I know of that can prevent my formset from working. I would really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance!

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.conf import settings

class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    concepts = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm, formset_factory
from relate.models import Topic

 class TopicForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ['name', 'concepts',]
```

views.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.conf import settings
from relate.forms import TopicForm
from django.views.generic import View
from django.forms import formset_factory
from relate.models import Topic

def relate_topics(request, method="POST"):
    TopicFormSet = formset_factory(TopicForm, extra=2, max_num=10, can_delete=True)
    if request.method == "GET":
        formset = TopicFormSet(request.GET or None)
    elif request.method == "POST":
        formset = TopicFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset:
                form.save()
            return redirect('index')
    return render(request, 'relate/relate_topics.html', {'formset': formset,})
```

relate_topics.html

```
    <h1>Hey</h1>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
    {% endfor %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

appname = 'relate'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^relate_topics/$', views.relate_topics, name='relate_topics'),
]
```

Comment: Can you post your imports as well. It seems to me as your TopicForm cannot be accessed through the 'relate' app. In which app is your model/form located?

Comment: Edited to include my imports @W.White My models.py and forms.py are both in the relate app.

Comment: If it's any help I was able to print the formset in the API. Could it be due to "render"?

Comment: If the form is valid you loop through formset and save each form. After saving all the available forms, you return redirect back to index. Replace it with the return render(request, 'relate/relate_topics.html'..... line to be redirected to another (probably the right) page. But you also have to think of what you want the system to do when the form is not valid etc and provide the correct redirect for it.